# How to extract a specific part from XML

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have an XML file from which I have to extract a specific part based on the id attribute.

## Input XML

```
<root>
<item id="id_1" state="closed">
    <content>
        <name>Details</name>
    </content>
    <item state="closed" id="id_1_1">
        <content>
            <name title="Name">Identity</name>
        </content>
        <item id="id_1_1_1" state="closed">
            <content>
                <name title="Name">Name</name>
            </content>
            <item id="id_1_1_1_1">
                <content>
                    <name title="First Name">First Name</name>
                </content>
            </item>
            <item id="id_1_1_1_2">
                <content>
                    <name title="Last Name">Last Name</name>
                </content>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item id="id_1_1_2" state="closed">
            <content>
                <name title="Address">Address</name>
            </content>
            <item id="id_1_1_2_1">
                <content>
                    <name title="Address Line 1">Line 1</name>
                </content>
            </item>
            <item id="id_1_1_2_2">
                <content>
                    <name title="Address Line 2">Line 2</name>
                </content>
            </item>
            <item id="id_1_1_2_3">
                <content>
                    <name title="City">City</name>
                </content>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
<item>
</root>
```

If I gave id_1_1 as input my output xml should be as below

## Output

```
<item id="id_1_1_1" state="closed">
    <content>
        <name title="Name">Name</name>
    </content>
</item>
<item id="id_1_1_2" state="closed">
    <content>
        <name title="Address">Address</name>
    </content>
</item>
```

The output should take the items immediate below the selected node(of input id), and not any depth further.

Comment: `name` is already two levels deeper than `item`, but you still want to include it, maybe you mean that you want to include anything but nested `item`s?

Comment: It this homework by any means?

Comment: I want to include the content and name but not the nested items. FYI, learning jquery, this is for generating tree using jstree plugin which takes XML data as input.

Comment: XPath alone will not suffice in this case. You need to selectively copy the XML you want from the hierarchy. You could use the XSLT from Dimitre as example. Or are you looking for an XQuery solution? That is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>

 <xsl:template match="item[@id='id_1_1']/item">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="content"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (slightly corrected to be made well-formed!):

```
<root>
    <item id="id_1" state="closed">
        <content>
            <name>Details</name>
        </content>
        <item state="closed" id="id_1_1">
            <content>
                <name title="Name">Identity</name>
            </content>
            <item id="id_1_1_1" state="closed">
                <content>
                    <name title="Name">Name</name>
                </content>
                <item id="id_1_1_1_1">
                    <content>
                        <name title="First Name">First Name</name>
                    </content>
                </item>
                <item id="id_1_1_1_2">
                    <content>
                        <name title="Last Name">Last Name</name>
                    </content>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item id="id_1_1_2" state="closed">
                <content>
                    <name title="Address">Address</name>
                </content>
                <item id="id_1_1_2_1">
                    <content>
                        <name title="Address Line 1">Line 1</name>
                    </content>
                </item>
                <item id="id_1_1_2_2">
                    <content>
                        <name title="Address Line 2">Line 2</name>
                    </content>
                </item>
                <item id="id_1_1_2_3">
                    <content>
                        <name title="City">City</name>
                    </content>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<item id="id_1_1_1" state="closed">
   <content>
      <name title="Name">Name</name>
   </content>
</item>
<item id="id_1_1_2" state="closed">
   <content>
      <name title="Address">Address</name>
   </content>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath:

```
//item[@id="id_1_1"]/item/content/name
```

will select all the `name` elements that are only for the direct child items of an `item` element at any level with the matching `id` attribute value.

**Edit**: If you want the `item` elements, use

```
//item[@id="id_1_1"]/item
```

and then use

```
./content/name
```

to select the immediate children of those during iteration.

Also, since you added a followup comment mentioning jQuery, note that its ["attribute equals selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) does not use the `@` symbol in the attribute names, nor does it use full XPath syntax.

Comment: I want to select the immediate items(with content and name) only and not the nested items.

Comment: What are the "immediate items"? It looks to me like the XPath I've provided gives the only relevant data in the output you requested. Nonetheless, I've edited my answer for possibly more information.